# C# Update my Database with a statment

Tags: c#, sql-update, primary-key

How can I update my column values in a table, with the help of primary key ?
Or can I override somehow the primary key?

Comment: Your question is too board. Have you tried anything!?

Comment: how are you accessing the database? You can create update statement in C# & pass it to the database.

Comment: Do you want to update other columns or the primary key value itself? Please explain your question properly.

Comment: how are you connecting to your database? and how are you trying to update? Can you show us some code where you are trying to achieve this

Comment: I have the primary key and i want with the primary key update the other columns.

Comment: although ive posted an answer, to get better help edit your question and add your code to ensure you can get the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Primary key is unique so you cannot change it. If you want to update the values using primary key then it is possible. But you cannot update the primary key.

Comment: @MagicMike:- Also note that some people may give you a workaround to update the primary key by removing the constraint temporarily but that is not a good practice and you should always avoid it.

Comment: you can update primary key " SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TABLE] ON ", just not add duplicates

Comment: @DieterB `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` is only needed if the PK column is an IDENTITY. Otherwise the PK can always be updated just as any other column as long as no other record in an other table references it.

Answer (score 1):

this question sounds like youre trying to do another insert rather than an update.

If you're doing

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values ('primaryKeyValue', 'col2val', 'col3val')
```

and then you try and do the same this will fail because of the primary key constraint.

you should be doing

```
update table set col1 = 'newValue', col2 = 'newValue2' where 'primaryKeyValue' = 'primaryKeyValue'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use update query :

```
update tablename set column1 = 'new1', column2 = 'new2', 'primaryKey' = 'newPKValue' where 'primaryKey' = 'PKValue';
```

just one thing to remember 'newPKValue' should not be duplicated.